# Databind Datagridview Combobox to a numeric field in c#.net 4.0

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I am trying to bind a numeric field in an oracle table to a Datagridview - combo list in windows forms.  With this what am trying to achieve is;
1 ) Based on the numeric value present in the number field, fetch ad display the respective string value in dataviewgridcombolist column.
2). When a new row is added in the datagrid view, the user may be allowed to select a listed (string) value in the combo list and the respective index value to be stored in the table back.

lots of thanks in advance..
Regards
Rithesh Krishnan

Answer (score 1):

I've created a customized grid control. Where you can specify each column type the respective editing control will be displayed - for the combo box column a combo box field will be displayed, for the numeric column a numeric editor will be displayed.

While user adding a new row also user will get these editors. Usage of this class as follows

```
customDataGrid1.ColumnDataTypeMapping.Add("EmployeeName", CustomDataGrid.CustomDataGridColumnType.TEXT);
customDataGrid1.ColumnDataTypeMapping.Add("ManagerID", CustomDataGrid.CustomDataGridColumnType.COMBOBOX);
customDataGrid1.ColumnDataTypeMapping.Add("JoinDate", CustomDataGrid.CustomDataGridColumnType.DATE);
customDataGrid1.ColumnDataTypeMapping.Add("DateOfBirth", CustomDataGrid.CustomDataGridColumnType.DATETIME);
customDataGrid1.ColumnDataTypeMapping.Add("Salary", CustomDataGrid.CustomDataGridColumnType.NUMERIC);
```